# linux touch relative time giving wrong result

Tags: bash, shell, time, touch

I'm using bash touch to change the date and time of a file. It works correctly if I simply specify the date and time. If, however, I use a relative time I get unexpected behavior.

```
$ date -R -r test.txt
Sat, 28 May 2022 02:56:22 -0400
$ touch -d '27 May 2022 05:31:12' test.txt
$ date -R -r test.txt
Fri, 27 May 2022 05:31:12 -0400
$ touch -d '27 May 2022 05:31:12 - 1 hour' test.txt
$ date -R -r test.txt
Fri, 27 May 2022 03:31:12 -0400
$ touch -d "27 May 2022 05:31:12 + 1 hour" test.txt
$ date -R -r test.txt
Fri, 27 May 2022 01:31:12 -0400
```

Note that although I asked for 1 hour earlier and then 1 hour later, it gave 2 hours earlier and 4 hours earlier respectively.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do your `touch`, you do no specify the timezone.  If you do, all your date arithmetic works ok.

EX:

```
$ touch -d '27 May 2022 05:31:12' test.txt
$ date -R -r test.txt
Fri, 27 May 2022 05:31:12 -0400
$
$ touch -d '27 May 2022 05:31:12 -0400 - 1 hour' test.txt
$ date -R -r test.txt
Fri, 27 May 2022 04:31:12 -0400
```